# What is an example of a closed manifold whose universal cover is not of finite homotopy type?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, cw-complexes

Does anyone know of an example of a closed manifold whose universal cover does not have the homotopy type of a finite CW complex?

(If the universal cover is also compact, then it is of finite homotopy type. The well known examples of closed manifolds having non-compact universal covers are aspherical manifolds, such as hyperbolic manifolds, tori, and products of these manifolds. In these examples the universal cover is contractile and so still has the homotopy type of a finite CW complex.)

Comment: Yes, think about 3-dimensional connected sums....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with a closed manifold $M$, necessarily of dimension $\ge 3$, with infinite fundamental group whose universal cover has nontrivial homology; the simplest example I can think of is $M = S^1 \times S^2$, whose universal cover $\widetilde{M}$ is $\mathbb{R} \times S^2$.

Now consider the connected sum $M\#M$ of two copies of $M$. Its fundamental group is the free product $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z} \cong F_2$. Its universal cover $\widetilde{M\#M}$ is a bit annoying to describe but basically looks like the [Cayley graph of $F_2$](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cayley_graph_of_F2.svg) but with the edges replaced by copies of $\widetilde{M}$ and the vertices replaced by the $S^2$'s used to connect-sum the copies of $M$ together. Together with the usual contraction of a tree this implies that its $H_2$ is a countable direct sum of copies of $H_2(\widetilde{M}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, which is not finitely generated. So $\widetilde{M\#M}$ does not have the homotopy type of a finite CW complex.

Comment: Actually I'm not as confident in that $H_2$ calculation as I'd like to be. I know that a construction of this form ought to work but the version of it I'm more comfortable with doesn't produce manifolds; we can take the wedge sum $S^2 \vee S^1$, whose universal cover is easy to directly visualize as a "line of balloons" and so which clearly has infinitely generated $H_2$. It ought to be possible to adapt this example to work with manifolds even if I messed up the details above. Maybe it would be easier to verify the details with something like $\mathbb{CP}^2 \# (S^3 \times S^1)$?

Comment: A different way to do it is to observe that the universal covering pace of the connected sum of $S^2\times S^1$'s is homeomorphic to the complement to a (tame) Cantor subset of $S^3$, and then apply the Alexander duality.

Comment: @Moishe: unfortunately I'm not familiar with either that homeomorphism nor with the fact that Alexander duality applies in that situation. Could you give more details in your own answer?

Comment: I think this is correct, but also that (as you suggest) it can be simplified by taking $M\#N$ with $N$ simply connected (though this needs $n\ge4$ to yield something non-trivial). Restricting $\tilde{M}\rightarrow M$ to $M\setminus B^n$ yields the universal cover of $M\setminus B^n$ as result of cutting a $\pi_1(M)$ worth of $B^n$ out of $\tilde{M}$. The universal cover of $M\#N$ is then obtained by gluing a $\pi_1(M)$ worth of $N\setminus B^n$ into this along the respective boundaries. Now, if $H_2(N)\neq0$, a Mayer-Vietoris computation yields that $H_2(\tilde{M\#N})$ is infinitely generated.